# Assertion failed error with opencv-contrib-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

So I'm using the latest version of `opencv-contrib-python`. I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sxvxge/Desktop/My Files/Code Projects/Python/Face recognition/FaceRecognitionRevamped.py", line 24, in <module>
    recognizer.read("face-trainer.yml")
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp:2145: error: (-215:Assertion failed) isMap() in function 'operator[]'
```

And it's because of the following line:

```
recognizer.read("face-trainer.yml")
```

`recognizer` is defined in the following line:

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

I saw an answer on [65023314](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65023314/opencv4-4-0-error-215assertion-failed-ismap-in-function-cvfilenode), however I can't figure out how to do as the answer says and fallback to `opencv2.4`. There is also another option to rebuild `opencv-contrib-python` using a c++ compiler but that's not really an option as I don't have such a compiler and I'm sure compiling it needs a lot more things than just downloading a compiler and the code, and I have no experience in c++, not to mention compiling such libraries can't be handled by my laptop as it's too slow. Also I only have `opencv-contrib-python` installed, as I was told having both `opencv-contrib-python` and `opencv-python` makes them interfere with each other. And the file `face-trainer.yml` exists in the same path as the main script.

Can someone guide me on how to fix my current issue?

I tried doing as the answer that I linked said, but I couldn't install `opencv2.4`. I expected my code to work as I'm using the latest version of `opencv-contrib-python`, but I got an error that was mentioned earlier.

Comment: [mre] required. -- no support for v2.4. your error message says you're using 4.6.0 so that is good. always use the latest version, not something from your linux's package repo.

Comment: related: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14908 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65023314/opencv4-4-0-error-215assertion-failed-ismap-in-function-cvfilenode